# How to make dragable texts with curve using Kinetic js in canvas?

Tags: html, html5-canvas, kineticjs

Can anybody have an idea , how to make text curves on dragable text using kinetic js in html5.

Comment: Your attachment is missing and also share what you have tried until now.

Comment: Oh I am sorry , I am new to stackoverflow and it is not allowing me to attach image in message, but any way Erick's reply helped me out.
@Erik: waiting for your tutorial on TextPath, hope it will be available soon.

Anyway Ani & Rana thanks for your intrest.

Cheers
Abhishek

Answer (score 1):

check out the TextPath shape.  It enables you to draw text along curves:

http://kineticjs.com/docs/symbols/Kinetic.TextPath.php

Will put up a tutorial as soon as possible.

Comment: Hey Eric,Thanks, this is what I was looking for, I got a code on jsfiddle to acheive the task: 
var textpath = new Kinetic.TextPath({ x: 0, y: 0, data: "M50,150 A120,120 0 1,1 50,155 Z", fontFamily: 'Tahoma', fontStyle: 'normal', fontSize: 38, text: 'abhishek', textFill: "#FF2222" }); 

But still not getting the paramater 'data' what is "M50,150 A120,120 0 1,1 50,155 Z" , i would be thankful if you could explain it. Thanks for your help. Cheers..