# Draggable, Sizable Text along an arch path using KineticJS

Tags: kineticjs

I've started a project using KineticJS, so far I have been able to accomplish everything I want except for text along an arched (circular) path. What I need is a sizable, draggable circular text, and I need to be able to keep track of the object. The TextPath object will not work for me, but I have been able to use the code from this example to get started http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-text-along-arc-path/

What I have been able to accomplish is taking this code and moving the layer (using slider controls) and adjusting the attributes (font, radius, angle) to get the effect I am looking for. What I would like to do is to be able to create multiple layers, drag the layers, and keep up with each layer by making the selectab.e. Since I am new to HTML 5 (and KineticJS) and don't full understand the layer object, I have a couple of questions to help me solve my issue. 1.) Can I drag a layer? I can't seem to make that work even though I make the layer draggable. 2.) Can a layer be use like a group, can it have size or does it default to the full size of the stage (canvas) object?

Also someone else had ask a simular question on this site but is very old and with no solution:

[How to make dragable texts with curve using Kinetic js in canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14079861/how-to-make-dragable-texts-with-curve-using-kinetic-js-in-canvas)

Any thoughts or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes you can drag a layer. But you need to add a "**transparent bg**" rectangle inside the layer before it can be dragged. Like this:

   ```
   var layer = new Kinetic.Layer({draggable: true});

   var bg = new Kinetic.Rect({
     width: stage.getWidth(),
     height: stage.getHeight()
   });

   layer.add(bg);
   ```
2. Yes layers can be used like a group, but I would **recommend** using groups to **group** objects instead of layers. Layers are more expensive than groups so use layers & groups where it makes **sense**. Layers & Groups can both have set sizes and I believe they both default to the size of the objects contained within them.

   See this thread for more information: [What are the differences between group and layer in KineticJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17632068/what-are-the-differences-between-group-and-layer-in-kineticjs)
3. **Textpath** should work for your needs, but you need to learn how to use [SVG Path Data](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_path.asp)

Here are a couple other pages that might be useful for you:

**Use an anchor to resize text**: [Drag and zoom text with Kineticjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17545365/drag-and-zoom-text-with-kineticjs/17601538#17601538)

**Select a node using** `e.targetNode`: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-get-event-shape-with-kineticjs/

**Drag & Drop & Resize**: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-resize-and-invert-images/